# css with crystal reports

Tags: css, crystal-reports

how can i use css with crystal report.there is no sheet to write the css.where can i write the css

Answer (score 0):

[Cascading Style Sheets for Customizing the CrystalReportViewer Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms225493%28VS.80%29.aspx).

[How to Change Crystal Report Formatting for Different Customers](http://bdotnet.in/blogs/dotnetstuff/archive/2008/10/07/how-to-change-crystal-report-formatting-for-different-customers-part-1.aspx)