# Crystal Reports Css Class

Tags: crystal-reports, css

Hello I'm new to Crystal Reports and wanted to use CSS to format the way my report looks.  However i'm stumped.  I re-read many tutorials online and it seemed pretty straightforward...but nothing worked.

I right clicked on sections that i wanted formatted on CR Designer.  I specified a CSS class name.  I then created a .css file with the styles--however i did not see any changes to my report. 
I also tried creating an HTML file with some CSS to see if that would perhaps affect the outcome of the look/feel of the report.  Again, nothing.

Is there something else i'm missing here??

Answer (score 1):

Since there are no answers to this question I'll throw a suggestion out there.

I'm sure you've probably got your issue figured out by now since this is an older question, but if you haven't then check out the answer to this question. There are 2 good links that discuss css and Crystal Reports.

[css with crystal reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077948/css-with-crystal-reports)